# Add markers to .NET trackbar

Tags: .net, timeline, trackbar, timelinemarkers

I'm using .NET trackbar to play data I've recorded on a device.
It works great and I use it as a time line in a video player. as you can see in this image:
[image: My good old timeline trackbar]

Now, when playing the data recorded from the device, some times the data contains ERRORS and WARNING values. I want to add markers/labels when special values occurs.
like in this image (Forgive me for my ugly drawing):
[image: My future trackbar]

In the above image I want to mark **on the trackbar** in yellow markers when a Warning occur and in red when Error occur.

how can I Implement this?
is there an opensource solution to this? - I know there are other track bars like:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/MAC_Slider.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/gTrackBar.aspx

but I \ dont think they solve my issue... plus I want to work with the .Net native trackbar.
maybe to draw on it??

an Example on how to draw on the trackbar properly (without strange flickering...) could really help me.
Thanks

Comment: Are the errors being painted when the trackbar is loaded, or as the video is playing?

Comment: I load al the data first and than play. I "know" all the errors location on the track bar bu i dont know how to draw the markers

Answer (score 2):

What you can go about doing is making a owner-drawn `trackbar`. This requires going in and overriding some of the appearance event handlers for the `trackbar`.

The `trackbar` is not a fun control to be modifying. Honestly what I would do, is just go ahead and put a "l" inside a  `label` and change the color accordingly. It will save you a lot of time and frustration.

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17395/Owner-drawn-trackbar-slider) is an example of user drawn `trackbar` though.